# Excepción java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. al tratar de usar pyjnius

Tags: java, python, kivy, jvm

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación **android** con python e intento utilizar **pyjnius** para implementar los módulos de **Java**
Cuando le doy un **import** a **jnius** no tengo problemas

[image: import jnius]

El detalle viene cuando intento importar cualquier parte de la **api de android**, pues obtengo el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He leído varias publicaciones con un error similar, sin embargo no encuentro la solución.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Quizás necesitas definir la CLASSPATH en Windows o alguna dependencia como Cython.

Comment: Estoy usando Cython 0.29.21
Y el path de JAVA_HOME (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin)
En la parte del Path añadí (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin\server) para que pueda acceder al archivo "jvm.dll"

Comment: Tal vez te sirva ver esto: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506319/pyjnius-import-jar-file]

Comment: ¡Hey!
Muchas gracias ya lo entendí

Comment: Si tienes la solución, puedes compartirla y que le sirva a alguien más.

Comment: Hice una comparación de la plataforma en la que se ejecutaba el código. 
from kivy.utils import platform

if platform == 'android':
    from jnius import autoclass
    .....
    .....

y con eso lo logré compilar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que pudiste dar con la solución sería importante ayudar a quien llegue a tener el mismo problema. Es importante colocar el código y no una imagen.

Se debe contar con algunas de pendencias como **Cython** antes de la instalación de la librería.

```
$ python -m pip install --upgrade cython
$ pip install pyjnius
```

Verificamos que tenemos instalada la librería con:

```
$ pip list
```

Finalmente, el código que nos compartiste:

```
from kivy.utils import platform 


def main():
    if platform == 'android': 
        from jnius import autoclass
        MediaRecorder = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder')
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Esto puede ayudar a los demás.